# vk_api python переход к другой функции

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

Пишу бота на `Python` для ВК, работаю с модулем [vk_api](https://github.com/python273/vk_api).
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно переходить к другой функции?
На примере кода:

```
{def main():
    elif event.text.lower() == 'Сложить'.lower(): #Если написали заданную фразу
        vk.messages.send(user_id=event.user_id,message=f'Первое число:',random_id=random.randint(1,99999999999999)) # Отвечаем пользоватю, мол введи первое число


def one_number():
    global number1
    number1 = event.text
    vk.messages.send(user_id=event.user_id,message=f'Второе число:',random_id=random.randint(1,99999999999999)) # Отвечаем пользоватю, мол введи второе число


def two_number():
    vk.messages.send(user_id=event.user_id,message=f'пам парам, сумма: ',random_id=random.randint(1,99999999999999)) # Отвечаем пользоватю, мол введи второе число
```

Есть функция `main`, дальше нужно перейти к функции `one_number`, а потом к `two_number`}
Как это реализовать?

Comment: пожалуйста, оформите код как код - значок {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    первая_фунцкия()
    вторая_функция()
```

Так же для генерации `random_id` в `vk_api.utils` есть функция `get_random_id`